# Rails ActionMailer Send Email Without Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

So, one of my projects has a SMTP server that has been configured to be used without any form of authentication. Here is my SMTP setting on `config/environments/production.rb`.

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'mail.example.com',
    port:                587,
    domain:               'info.example.com',
    user_name:            'no-reply@example.com',
    password:             '',
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none',
    authentication:       nil,
    tls:                  false,
    enable_starttls_auto: false
}
```

I though the `authentication` mode needs to be set to `nil` but, when I tried to send email, it gave me this error.

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > CustomerMailer.test.deliver
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
```

Any solution, guys?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're specifying authentication details. ActionMailer will accordingly use them.

Solution: Don't.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'mail.example.com',
    port:    587,
    domain:  'info.example.com'
}
```

(The `domain` parameter may itself be unnecessary depending on your server configuration.)

Comment: It gave me `ArgumentError: SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase` error.

Comment: I setup a local [Postfix SMTP server](https://gist.github.com/raelgc/6031274) for testing emails in my Rails app in dev. I also needed `:openssl_verify_mode => 'none'`. The domain wasn't required. In my `development.rb` I have this configuration: `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp; config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :addres  => 'localhost',  :port => 25, :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'}`